# Hide VoLTE icon on Samsung

Tags: samsung, 4g, voice-over-lte

I used to be able to turn off VoLTE, but since a recent update, if I select 5G, VoLTE can't be disabled anymore (it is grayed out). I don't mind it being on, I just want to hide the icon.

[image]

If I select 4G I can disable it. That's what's working for me now. But then I can't use 5G connectivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, just found a way. Get `Good Lock` from Galaxy Store, and then get `QuickStar`. It have an option to hide the icon.

[image]